# Prevent submission if fields do not match

Tags: javascript, html

I am using JS to check if two fields match but I need a way to disable the submit button if they fail to match and then enable once they do match:

```
    <label>New password:</label><br><input type="password" name="new_password"  id="password1"/><br><br>
    <label>Confirm password:</label><br><input type="password" name="new_password_check"  id="password2" /><br><br>

    <p id="validate-status"></p>

  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#password2").keyup(validate);
});


function validate() {
  var password1 = $("#password1").val();
  var password2 = $("#password2").val();
    if(password1 == password2) {
       $("#validate-status").text("Passwords Match!");        
    }
    else {
       $("#validate-status").text("Passwords Do Not Match!");  
    }

}
```

**UPDATED**

```
<form method="post" action="password_change.inc.php">

    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<? echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>" />


    <label>New password:</label><br><input type="password" name="new_password"  id="password1"/><br><br>
    <label>Confirm password:</label><br><input type="password" name="new_password_check"  id="password2" /><br><br>

    <p id="validate-status"></p>   

    <input id="#submit-button" type="submit" value="Change password" />
</form>

<script>

function validate() {
    var password1 = $("#password1").val();
    var password2 = $("#password2").val();
    if(password1 == password2) {
         $("#validate-status").text("Passwords Match!");
         $('#submit-button').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
         $("#validate-status").text("Passwords Do Not Match!");  
         $('#submit-button').prop('disabled', true);
    }
}

</script>
```

I have updated my code as per a kind suggestion below but it will still allow me to post the form without disabling until the fields match...

Comment: One flaw I see in this is the event is fired for #password2 only. What if they make them match then change #password1? Why not do the check on submit OR do a $(.class).blur on both passwords OR both?

Comment: So what would be a better method?

Comment: Simply bind `validate()` to keyup on `#password1` too, the same way you are for `#password1`

Comment: Your id attribute in the HTML should not contain a hash character (i.e. it should simply be `<input id="submit-button"` (as you have correctly done with your other elements)

Comment: @karthik as in the OP's code, you need to remove the `#` from the submit button's ID attribute in the HTML.

Comment: @TomJenkins Still fails even when the id has no # my bad I should have spotted that

Comment: It's probably time to open up your JS console and see if you're getting any errors, etc. In Chrome or Firefox hit F12 (or Cmd+Shift+i on Mac) and select the console tab. Meanwhile, I'm throwing your code into a JSFiddle to see what's going on.

Comment: This JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/kzwhLns8/) works and is a minimally altered version of your original code. I would strongly recommend you review the advice given by myself and @karthik here as to improvements, especially caching elements, running validate when either password element changes .

Comment: I added a response as an answer which is being downvoted for some reason.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're almost there. Set the `disabled` property on your submit button (which appears to be missing from your pasted code). Assuming your submit button has an id `submit-button`:

```
function validate() {
    var password1 = $("#password1").val();
    var password2 = $("#password2").val();
    if(password1 == password2) {
         $("#validate-status").text("Passwords Match!");
         $('#submit-button').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
         $("#validate-status").text("Passwords Do Not Match!");  
         $('#submit-button').prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

An optimised version would "cache" the elements like so:

```
var $password1 = $("#password1"),
    $password2 = $("#password2"),
    $statusMessage = $("#validate-status"),
    $submitButton = $('#submit-button');

function validate() {

    if($password1.val() == $password2.val()) {
         $statusMessage.text("Passwords Match!");
         $submitButton.prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
         $statusMessage.text("Passwords Do Not Match!");  
         $submitButton.prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

Comment: your `true` and `false` should be reversed.

Comment: So I am trying the above but it still allows me to push the submit button?

Comment: are you sure your selector for your submit button in your JavaScript matches the ID (or other selector) in your HTML? jQuery won't error if `$submitButton` doesn't match anything, even when you run `.prop()`

Comment: Yep the Id on the submit matches the selector in the JS - I will update my question...

Comment: @phpcoder i don't mind if you accept this answer, but this is not the best way to do it.

Comment: @karthik I am very thankful and will be reading up on what you have all suggested.

Answer (score 2):

If your submit button id is "submit", you can do :

```
      $("#submit").prop('disabled', true);​
```

(you might want to  validate on clicking the submit button also)

So you should try something like :

```
   if(password1 == password2) {
      $("#validate-status").text("Passwords Match!");     
       $("#submit").prop('disabled', false);​

   }
   else {
      $("#validate-status").text("Passwords Do Not Match!");  
      $("#submit").prop('disabled', false);​
  }
```

**But I would suggest you to write it this way:**

As you are submitting the form, it's better to do the validation on submitting the form, because  by calling `validate` on `keyup` you will be doing lot of unnecessary work.

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Change password" onSubmit="return validate();" />

function validate(){
    return ($("#password1").val() === $("#password2").val());
}
```

writing `onSubmit=" return validate();` in your form submit button prevents the form from submitting when the `validate` function returns false. So you don't need to write any other code. This should be enough.

Comment: How would your above suggestion look if all put together?

Comment: @karthik I think it translates to "please write my code for me".

Comment: Sorry you have edited it, so the last part would do both the check for matches and also do the validation too?

Comment: @TomJenkins That isn't what I am asking at all - I am confused by his response

Comment: @phpcoder Checking for match is the only validation right?

Comment: that is correct yeah - so essentially I want to ensure both the fields match and only when they do match that the submit button becomes available or prevent a way to stop the form from submitting until they match

Comment: Sorry, I posted a comment in the wrong place. @karthik the submit button won't match the JS selector because it's ID begins with a `#`. Remove the `#` from the `id` attribute in the HTML and the selector will match.

Comment: @TomJenkins yeah , thanks :) I did not pay much attention to that. edited :)

Answer (score 0):

Give both password elements a class and do a .blur().

```
$('.myClass').blur(function () { value is the same enable submit, else disable  });
```

I would put a check on the submit function as well and if the values are not the same return false and some message saying the passwords don't match

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to remove that # from your input id. It would probably make sense to disable it on load as well.

input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Change password" disabled="true"

Then just set a keyup listener on both password fields

$("#password1, #password2").keyup(function (e) { validate(); });

(Based on your updated code)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for adding to a 5-year old question, but here is another way of doing it...

```
<form method="post" action="password_change.inc.php">

    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<? echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>" />


    <label>New password:</label><br><input type="password" name="new_password"  id="password1"/><br><br>
    <label>Confirm password:</label><br><input type="password" name="new_password_check"  id="password2" /><br><br>

    <p id="validate-status"></p>   

    <input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Change password" />
</form>

<script>

$('#password1, #password2').keyup(validate); // Allows for interchangeable user text - Example, if user types in password1 field, but actually has password2 field with the correct password, user can correct password1 field and things match/validate
function validate() {
    var password1 = $("#password1").val();
    var password2 = $("#password2").val();
    if(password1 == password2) {
         $('#validate-status').css({'background' : 'green'});
         $('#validate-status').text('Passwords Match');
         // Below commented out code works too...
         //$('#submit-button').prop('disabled', false);
         $('#submit-button').css({'display' : 'block'}); // Bring the submit button back...
    }
    else {
         $('#validate-status').css({'background' : 'red'});
         $('#validate-status').text('Passwords do NOT match - Please fix');
         // Below commented out code works too...
         //$('#submit-button').prop('disabled', true);
         $('#submit-button').css({'display' : 'none'}); // Do not display the submit button - user has no choice but to correct passwords and make them match...
    }
}

</script>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8kLypb7q/1/